# auto mix api when self typing in Scala

Tags: scala

This is somehow unexpected in scala(or my expectation is wrong). So following are some sample code:

```
trait A
trait B

trait HasA { def foo: A }
trait HasB { def foo: B }
```

so far so good, then i do

```
scala> trait HasBoth extends HasA with HasB
<console>:11: error: overriding method foo in trait HasA of type => A;
 method foo in trait HasB of type => B has incompatible type
       trait HasBoth extends HasA with HasB
```

Alright, I see the error. it makes sense.

but the confusion comes following:

```
trait Wrapper[T] { def get: T }
trait HasBoth2 { self: Wrapper[HasA with HasB] => def bar = get.foo }
```

this I found it's insane. if we check the type of `bar`, its `B`. if we flip the order, such that the constraint is `HasB with HasA`, then `bar` is `A`.

so we have some inconsistency here. I would expect either of:

1. `HasA with HasB` yield `{ def foo: A with B }` automatically, or
2. `HasBoth2` yields a type incompatibility error.

please kindly explain this inconsistency, or it's a type system bug.

Update

```
trait HasBoth3 extends HasA with HasB { def foo: A with B }
type Wrapped = Wrapper[HasBoth3]
```

Wrapped will satisfy the constraint of HasBoth2.

Comment: It seems that here is just a confusion of types vs classes, type `HasA with HasB` is just a type constraint, and `trait HasBoth` is an attempt to create class.

Comment: @dmitry still it doesn't explain the self typing. The type contradicts to the constraint

Comment: Only `null` casted to `HasA with HasB` can actually meet the type constraint, so it hardly matters.

Comment: Actually, it seems like a bug or rather an unpredicted use case. Also as @m-z said you cannot do anything with that declaration.

Comment: @dmitry that's not true. I can implement something that implements  HasA and HasB at the same time. Why you say null is the only case? No classes involved here so it's definitely possible.

Comment: @m-z please see above

Comment: Please show me a concrete implementation of `HasBoth2` that does not throw an exception when you call `bar`.

Comment: @m-z update will satisfy the constraint

Comment: I asked for a _concrete_ example, not an abstract trait. If you try to implement this as a class, it will not work.

Comment: @m-z i see your point. you didn't get my question. i am not asking why this code won't work. but rather, my question is the type system behaves different from both of my expectations. i expected either, type error, as you said it doesn't quite make sense, or type system can be smarter at this point and figure out my intention. if you look at `HasBoth2` and reason the type of `bar`, i think it's very convincing that it should be typed as `A with B`. but type system doesn't either give error or try to be smart, but gives `B`. this is a problem and inconsistency.

Comment: @m-z in terms of whether the program is realistic or not, it doesn't matter that much in the scope of the discussion.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr result of bar cannot be `A with B` . Even if `Wrapper[HasA with HasB].get` has type `HasA with HasB` it says conflicting information on type of `foo`. Typechecker somehow supposes that return type is from the last one in composition, it may be a shortcoming. But there's no any dependency between `Has` trait and return type of `foo` anyway. So, `(HasA with HasB).foo` having type `A with B` seems to be a suggestion with no ground.

Comment: @dmitry then it's no better to assume `foo` returns `B` in this case also. it sounds to me we are concluding that it's a type system bug, by type checking an uninstantiable trait definition.

Comment: I see you opened a ticket on this at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9769

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. It is one of scala's core points of unsoundness.

[SI-7278: Unsoundess in many guises](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7278)

I offer some explanation in [SI-7255](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7255), reproduced in part below.

*This seems to be a pretty fundamental failure of the type system, and maybe part of the motivation for dotty.*

*Abstract type members aren't unified as normally implied by the word; they can only be refined. What that means in this context is that a type is created which is the intersection of B with its self type, that is, B with A. The intersection type is created assuming it can just use the last 'C' in the linearization, since the compile will fail in refchecks unless the last 'C' is a refinement of any earlier 'C's.*

*This system breaks down with self types, because a class sees itself as having the intersection of the declared class and the declared self type. Either X with Y or Y with X might be valid instantiations; there is no way a priori to know which is the "last" member C.*

For yet more color, see my last comment on [SI-7472](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7472).